# How do I decrypt files with gpg / gnupg without loosing the original file permissions?

Tags: shell-script, permissions, encryption, gpg

I am currently trying to automate the encryption and decryption of a collection of files. For the encryption I currently use:

```bsh
gpg --batch --recipient [RECIPIENT] --encrypt-files [FILES]
```

For the decryption I use pretty much the same:

```bsh
gpg --batch --decrypt-files [FILES]
```

But both during encryption as well as decryption the original file permissions are lost:

```bsh
$ gpg --batch --recipient aram --encrypt-files foo
$ ls -l foo*
-rw------- 1 aram aram foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 aram aram foo.gpg

$ rm foo && gpg --batch --decrypt-files foo
$ ls -l foo*
-rw-r--r-- 1 aram aram foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 aram aram foo.gpg
```

I am OK with it during encryption, I can set the file permissions manually. But during decryption, as well as posing a security risk, some files like ssh keys use functionality without proper permissions.

Is there a mechanism that retains file permissions during batch decryption?

Of course I can loop over the files, read the permission, decrypt and then set the permissions again. But that kind of defeats the point of batch decrypting.

---

There is an open issue on gnupg.org that's 4 years old now and hasn't had much activity since then: https://dev.gnupg.org/T2945

Comment: You can encrypt a tar archive of these files.

Comment: there does not seem to be a way to make `gpg` do it for you. gpg alternatives like age have the same issue. they don't care about preserving file permissions. you could set `umask` yourself or wrap things in `tar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@a-b](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/251756/a-b) and [@frostschutz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/30851/frostschutz) suggested, wrapping the files in a `tar` file and then encrypting is an option.

However, I would like to have access to the original file structure without decrypting. For now, I have resorted to aligning the file permissions after the batch decryption. This has the additional benefit of aligning permissions when the decrypted files are already lying around on disk:

```bsh
gpg --batch --decrypt-files $files

for encrypted in $files ; do
  decrypted=${encrypted%.gpg}
  chmod --reference="$encrypted" -- "$decrypted"
done
```

Of course, the alignment can also be done after each decrypted file:

```bsh
for encrypted in $files ; do
  gpg --decrypt-files "$encrypted"

  decrypted=${encrypted%.gpg}
  chmod --reference="$encrypted" -- "$decrypted"
done
```

If you want to be absolutely sure that the decrypted file never has more permissions than the encrypted file, you can use a temporary dummy file and force `gpg` to overwrite it:

```bsh
for encrypted in $files ; do
  decrypted=${encrypted%.gpg}

  touch "$decrypted" && chmod --reference="$encrypted" -- "$decrypted"
  gpg --yes --decrypt-files "$encrypted"
done
```

The same mechanism can be used for aligning permissions after encryption. I have not done any performance testing, not sure if one of the options is faster.

---

I will not accept this as an answer right away, maybe somebody comes up with a better solution than this.

Comment: Since you're using GNU coreutils (based on the way you use `stat`), you can use `chmod --reference="$encrypted" -- "$decrypted"` instead of calling `stat`. Or `getfacl -- "$encrypted" | setfacl --set-file=- -- "$decrypted"` to copy ACL and not just traditional permissions.